# Problem on directed graph involving $\gcd$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ a directed graph. Suppose that $p$ is the greatest common divisor of the lengths of closed paths of $G$. How one can prove that there exists a partition $V_0,...,V_{p-1}$ of $V$ such that for every $(v_1,v_2)\in E$ there is $ 0\leq i\leq p$ with $v_1\in V_i$ and $v_2\in V_{i+1}$

Edit:

$$V_0=V_p$$

Comment: Does "closed paths" = "cycles"?

Comment: @CalvinLin: Yes.

Comment: Well, first of all, did you really mean in the last sentence $0\leq i<p$? Because with $i=p$, it is unclear what you mean by $V_i$. Also, presumably, with $i=p-1$, presumably $V_{i+1}=V_0$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I added the required!

Comment: What is the value of $p$ if $G$ has no cycles?

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones: I don't know.

Comment: If you assume the directed graph is strongly connected and read "closed path" by "cycle", the result is true. This comes up in the Perron-Frobemius theorem.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: Could you please post a link proving that theorem?

Comment: The question for strongly connected digraphs is now [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479364/problem-on-strongly-connected-directed-graph-involving-gcd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this theorem is true. You need some additional condition, like every edge is on some cycle (and I'm not even sure that is enough.)

Let $V=\{A,B,C,D,E\}$ be the vertices and define the directed edges as $\{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(A,D),(D,E),(A,E)\}$.  The graph is drawn below:

[image: Drawing of the graph]

In this graph, there is one cycle, $A,B,C$, and thus $p=3$.

WLOG, we can put $A\in V_0$. Then since $(A,D)$ and $(A,E)$ are edges, $D,E\in V_1$. But then since $(D,E)$ is an edge, and $D\in V_1$, $E\in V_2$. Which contradicts that $V_1,V_2,V_3$ is a partition, since $E\in V_1$ and $E\in V_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the picture, @Douglas.

Comment: It looks like a counterexample to me.  I wonder if this is a homework question; the lecturer might have a surprise when the assignments are returned.  (I suppose the theorem would be true if there were no "incoherent" cycles.)

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones The other thing I've seen quite often here is that the OP has failed to transcribe the whole question. There were clearly oddities above ($0\leq i\leq p$ for example, when $0\leq i\leq p-1$ is enough.)